# Assigning variable with $.getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am creating a chart with nvd3. Since i am pretty new to javascript i've got a little problem assigning the chartdata. 
When i assign it like this:

```
var long_short_data = [
  {
    "key": "ISP",
    "color": "#d62728",
    "values": [
      {
        "label" : "oäop" ,
        "value" : 9000
      } ,...
    ]
  },
    {
    "key": "Organization",
    "color": "#d67548",
    "values": [
      {
        "label" : "amklöericalököky" ,
        "value" : 8000
      },...
    ]
  }
];
```

The graph is displayed as it should. 
But when i assign it like this:

```
var long_short_data = $.getJSON( "/link/to/multiBarHorizontalData.json", function() {
console.log( "success" );
})
```

It doesnt. 
These are my console logs:

```
success
nvd3.js:9229 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you are probably trying to use the data before the asynchronous .getJSON() method finishes.

Comment: You should check if you JSON is valid with a JSON validator

Comment: Try assigning your `long_short_data` inside the `.done` callback of your `$.getJSON()` function as  `var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "/link/to/multiBarHorizontalData.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
}).done(function(data) {
    long_short_data = data;
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, solved it trying @Leopard 's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` doesn't return result as you are expecting. It returns data in `callback`. It should be

```
$.getJSON( "/link/to/multiBarHorizontalData.json", function(result) {
   long_short_data = result;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It does work now. Will accept your answer as soon as i can.